# EF 4: Update model based only on fields that exist in the view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Say I have a model:

```
public class HashTable {
   public string sKey { get;set; }
   public string sValue { get:set; }
}
```

Then I render it in a view:

```
<div>Please enter the key/value pair:</div>
@Html.LabelFor(h => h.sKey, "Key");
@Html.TextBoxFor(h => h.sKey);
@Html.LabelFor(h => h.sValue, "Value");
@Html.TextBoxFor(h => h.sValue);
```

Then I save it in the controller:

```
db.HashTable.Add(themodel);
```

Then I recall it in a view, but I only want to change the value:

```
<div>Please enter the value:</div>
Key: @Model.sKey
@Html.LabelFor(h => h.sValue, "Value");
@Html.TextBoxFor(h => h.sValue, Model.sValue);
```

Then I submit that to the controller. The problem is if I do:

```
db.Entry(oldmodel).CurrentValues.SetValues(themodel);
```

It nulls the "key" field because there's no  element on the view for it.

This is a very simple example (the code might not all be exact) of a very complex system where certain form fields may or may not be displayed in the view based on the state of the ticket. What I really need is a way to make it so that if the form field is not displayed in the view, it is not updated in the database. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Include your Key also in the form. So that when posted back, It will be available in the model/viewmodel. You can use Html.HiddenFor helper method for this.

```
<div>Please enter the value:</div>
Key: @Model.sKey
@Html.LabelFor(h => h.sValue);
@Html.TextBoxFor(h => h.sValue);
@Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.sKey)
```

**EDIT**: If there are so many fields which you dont want to show in the view, but still want to save with valid existing data, I would have the ID of that entry ( Ex : ProductId) in my view and use that Id to build the existing Product object and apply the new changes to that and save back. some thing like this

```
<div>Please enter the value:</div>
Key: @Model.sKey
@Html.LabelFor(h => h.ProductPrice);
@Html.TextBoxFor(h => ProductPrice);
@Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.ProductId)
```

and the action method will looks like

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit (ProductViewModel newModel)
{
  var oldProduct=repositary.GetProduct(newModel.ProductID);
  oldProduct.ProductPrice=newModel.ProductPrice;

  //Now save the oldProdcut

}
```

Comment: If I do that, I'm going to have to write a very long and complex conditional for when hidden fields will or will not appear on the view, which is exactly what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Only for the primary key, which is required to update the row in the database. Other fields will not require this step.

Comment: @mgnoonan: Yea.I would always do that way only. Since his example class doesn't have an ID field i did not mention that. But i have a second part in my answer to explain that.

Comment: Again, if I use a method to write the "old model"'s fields to the "new model" one by one, I'm going to have to write a long and complex conditional for when fields will or will not be replaced. What I'm looking for is something that checks for the existence of the element on the view and overwrites it only if it does.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you'll need to render the primary key(s) as a hidden element.

```
<div>Please enter the value:</div> 
Key: @Model.sKey 
@Html.HiddenFor(h => h.sKey) 
@Html.LabelFor(h => h.sValue); 
@Html.TextBoxFor(h => h.sValue);
```

Then use the `UpdateModel()` method in the Edit action of your controller. [This helper function copies the values from the form collection to the model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee264031.aspx). There's no need to figure out which fields were editable, as `UpdateModel` does this for you.

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Edit(int id, FormCollection formValues)
{
    HashTable hash = repository.GetHashTable(id);
    UpdateModel(hash);
    repository.Save();
    return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = hash.DinnerID });
}
```

Comment: What I'm really looking for is a way that doesn't require me to overwrite fields that haven't changed.

Comment: Well, you must have the PK *somewhere*, otherwise you can't retrieve (or update) the row from the database. You don't have to do this for all fields, just those in the PK. I don't think you can get around this limitation, so your choice is to pull the value from the form data or from the URL.

Comment: Could you use the `UpdateModel()` method? Modified my answer above.